# jQuery Mobile: creating an object from JSON via $.getJSON()

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Newbie Question:

I successfully get a json collection of books from the server:

```
        $.getJSON("/Data/json.txt", function (data) {
            //Book array?
        });
```

Given the JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "Books":[
      {
         "ID":"42",
         "Name": "AJAX"
       },
      {
         "ID":"41",
         "Name": "Sand"
       }
    ]
 }
```

How do I get a populated "Book" collection ? (I'm coming from a C# background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will already have the books array inside data. Like this:

```
 $.getJSON("/Data/json.txt", function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Books.length; i++) {
            var id = data.Books[i].ID;
            var name = data.Books[i].Name;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `i < data.Books` should probably be `i < data.Books.length`

Comment: That's perfect. I didn't think it would be nicely hydrated.

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be the JSON data structure sent back by the server, so `data.Books` would be the array of 'Book' objects.  These are javascript objects that represent a 'Book', although the individual objects have no idea themselves what type they are.  Just treat them as 'Books', and you should be fine.